# How to implement automatic page data refresh ASP.NET Core + Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I'm using **ASP.NET Core** + **Angular** (@angular/cli v10.2.0).

I have component that shows list of ***Broadcasts*** I have in database. ***Broadcast*** entity has "***InfoString***".
I have another component that shows only ***InfoString*** of particular ***Broadcast***.

**User1** opens **BroadcastComponent** page.
**User2** opens **InfoString** page.

Everything is fine. Both see relevant data.

But when **User1** updates ***Broadcast*** entity and changes ***InfoString***.
**User2** does not see changes until page is **refreshed**.

What should I use to refresh data for **User2** without him needed to refresh page manually?
Tried [this](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service) component interaction guide via service, does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one you specified - Parent and children communicate via service only works on a page. Not between two client/browser instances. You need to use SignalR or similar technologies for real-time data updates. Since you're using ASP.NET Core, SignalR is the better choice. Checkout - [Tutorial: Get started with ASP.NET Core SignalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio&WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5002040)